# How to prevent adding the same files to a list using os.listdir?

Tags: python, priority-queue, shutil, listdir

I'm developing a mechanism that sends archives to FTP server. It uses a PriorityQueue. The process of sending files is like that:

1. Scan the `ReadyToSend` folder for the `.tar` archives and put their names into `listOfArchives` list.
2. For each `archive` in `listOfArchives` determine the sending priority and put the name of the archive with corresponding priority to the `SendingQueue`.
3. Using `shutil` move archive to another directory, to prevent it from being added to `listOfArchives` again in the next scan.

Is there any possible way to exclude adding archive to `listOfArchives` and thus adding it again to the `SendingQueue` without moving archive to another directory just after adding it to the `SendingQueue`?

Here is a sample code:

```
def send_queue_builder(self):
    while True:
        listOfArchives = [f for f in os.listdir(self.readyToSendDir) if f.endswith('.tar')]
        for archive in listOfArchives:
            #code that determines priority
            self.SendingQueue.put(archive,priority)
            shutil.move(archive,newDirectory)
        time.sleep(20)

def ftp_sender(self):
    print('SENDER: Begin sending...')   
    while True:
        if self.sendQueue.empty() != True:
            # command below automatically gets the archive with the highest priority
            archive = self.sendQueue.get()
            # send archive using subprocess.call
        else:
            time.sleep(20)
a = threading.Thread(target=send_queue_builder)
b = threading.Thread(target=ftp_sender)
a.start()
b.start()
a.join()
b.join()
```

I'd be really thankful for any hint bringing me closer to the solution.

Comment: Are you trying to find duplicates by name? If not, I didn't really understand what you are looking for

Comment: Let's assume that `arch1.tar` and `arch2.tar` are in the `ReadyToSend` directory. the `send_queue_builder` starts scanning and builds the list `listOfArchives` that now contains `arch1.tar` and `arch2.tar`. for-loop is putting each element from list to the `sendQueue`. Without moving `arch1.tar` and `arch2.tar` to another directory, they will be included in each scan and thus put to the `sendQueue` again and again making the queue infinitely long. Is there any way of preventing such behaviour without moving files to another directory after putting them to the queue?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to keep track of a list of already sent archives in your class / wherever you are executing this and when scanning for new archives see if the archive you are currently at, is already in that list of sent archives. If it is, just discard it and move on

Comment: I would say that I'd like to track a list of archives already **put** to the `sendQueue`. Let's say, that when an archive was put to the `sendQueue` once, do not include it in `listOfArchives`(and thus in sendQueue) again.